# Set screen orientation of application in android

Tags: android

Here is my code to set orientation of screen

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.srikanth.lullaby.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:configChanges="orientation"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.srikanth.lullaby.SoundRecordingActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.srikanth.lullaby.RecorderActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
         android:name="com.srikanth.lullaby.MediaplayerExample"
         android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.srikanth.lullaby.MediaPlayerActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
```

but it is not working properly ,when i rotate the screen then app changing its direction
How to fix this.

Comment: remove android:configChanges="orientation" from all activities..

Comment: Tried but issue not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

Just **remove**

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Or in your java add this line after `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);`

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: @Prabha you can try to set **programmatically** in `Java`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add like this for every activity tag:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.srikanth.lullaby.RecorderActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Comment: once read the question he wants the screen orientation portrait not the Activity state when orientation change..

Comment: i am not talking about activity tag..with using your code screen orientation change but onCreate called only once..Activity state is maintained..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

use theme in Application tag

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

`The android:configChanges line prevents onResume(), onPause() from being called when the screen is rotated. Without this line, the rotation will stay as you requested but the calls will still be made.`

`keyboardHidden and orientation are required for < Android 3.2 (API level 13), and all three options are required 3.2 or above, not just orientation.`